# Errors in my code that indicates illegal modifier and syntax error, "VariablesDeclarators"

Tags: java, methods, overloading

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rectangle {

    private static double setLength1 = 0;
    private static double setWidth1 = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println(" Today we`ll find the dimensions of a rectangle."); }                       
                        public setLength1(double setLength1);
                        {
                            double setlength1;
                            System.out.println("What is the length: ");
                            Scanner scan;
                            setLength1 = scan.nextDouble();
                            return setLength1;
                        }
                        public setWidth1(double setWidth1);
                        {
                            double setWidth1;
                            System.out.println("What is the Width: ");
                            Scanner scan;
                            setWidth1 = scan.nextDouble();
                            return setWidth1;
                        }
                        double getArea;
                        {
                            return setWidth1 * setLength1;
                        }
                        double getPerimeter;
                        {
                            return 2*(setWidth1+setLength1);
                        }
    }
}
```

I initially tried to replace the public with a double but met with a suggest from the software to replace the public static void to public static double. On line 14 and 22, I added parenthesis and add (double seWidth1) and (double setLength1). That following actions would give me Syntax error on token "public", record expected after this token, Syntax error, insert "RecordBody" to complete RecordDeclaration, Syntax error on token "public", record expected after this token, and Syntax error, insert "RecordBody" to complete RecordDeclaration for line 14.

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: Why do you have methods declared inside `main`?